# Required attribute HTML5; message position

Tags: html, position, required

I have been building a site in html5; recently my browser (Chrome) updated and now the nifty required attributes are working :)

On the down side... the message telling you that the field is required appears bellow the input, right on top of another control :(

Is there a way to make the message go to the right of the input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nop, the message displayed varies depending on the browser implementation. There is nothing you can do to change it(other than implementing your own validation).

Rest assured that in a few releases that will get a better look;)